# How to make a request get by retrofit Android

Tags: android, json, rest, get, retrofit

This is my Api response, What I don't know, is whether it is a `json object` or a `json array`.

I need create a `GET` request with retrofit but I dont know

```
{
    "Customers": [
        {
            "Empresa": "CORSENESA",
            "Cliente": "1000      ",
            "Nombre": "ANDREA ARRIOLA LOPEZ                                                                                ",
            "Direccion": "7 AV. 9-64 ZONA 9\r\n\r\n",
            "telefonos": "4710-7975                                                   ",
            "DiasCredito": 0,
            "inactivo": false,
            "DiasVisita": "L,M,MI,J,V,S,D"
        },
        {
            "Empresa": "CORSENESA",
            "Cliente": "1005      ",
            "Nombre": "TANIA LOPEZ HERNANDEZ                                                                     STA. PAULA",
            "Direccion": "PASEO SAN CRISTOBAL ZONA 8 DE MIXCO",
            "telefonos": "53071090                                                    ",
            "DiasCredito": 0,
            "inactivo": false,
            "DiasVisita": "L,M,MI,J,V,S,D"
        }
     ]
}
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific ?

Comment: It is a Json Object with Json Array inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a serious suggestion developer to developer, you need to learn your basics. Just to help you, above is JSON array, I will tell you the steps

(Assuming you are using android studio)

1. ```
   implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.0' & also 
   implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
   ```

in your app: gradle file

2. Create an interface and write your GET method something like:

```
interface yourinterfacename {

 @GET("your url path after base url")
 Call<YourResponseModelCalss> getData();
}
/* baseurl: Say Eg: yourdomain.com/user/data then yourdomain.com/ is ur base url 
& user/data will be your path */

class YourResponseModelCalss {

private List<RespData> Customers; /* make sure 'Customers' is same as mentioned in response else you will not get any data.*/

public static class RespData {

private String Empresa; 

... /* add all your paramters as in the response, make sure parameters name should match exact as mentioned in api response */

// implement getters and setters
}

}
```

Now  once you do this you need build retrofitObject

,,,

retroObject = new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .client(httpClient.build())
                    .addConverterFactory(
                            GsonConverterFactory.create(new Gson()))
                    .build();

/* make sure use it in a different class and implement static method in the class so that you can get the the instance of the retro object with return type Retrofit

something like -> public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() { }

*/
,,,

Now lets make an API call

```
YourInterfaceName service = RetroClassIntancename.YourRetroObjectMethodName().create(YourInterfaceName.class)

Call<yourinterfacename> call = service.getData() // remember the method name you created in your interface

call.enqueue(new Callback<YourResponseClassName>() {
  @Override
  public void onResponse(Response<YourResponseClassName> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
    // your code if it is successfull
  }

  @Override
  public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
    // if it fails
  }
});
```

Above is rough implementation. There are many good tutorials out there to refer.

Hope this helps. Happy coding :)